# Persisting a backbone model and the id

Tags: backbone.js

Let's assume we create a new model class an instanciate a person using it:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/user'
});

var nou = new User({
   name: "nourdine"
});
```

Now, of course, we want to persist it. Not having added an `id` backbone will create a POST request and communicate the server the intention to create an entity under `/user` containing the data `{name: "nourdine"}`. Here's how we do it:

```
nou.save(null, {
    success: function (model, response, options) {
       // ... what do I do here?
    }
})
```

The server will now create a record in the db containing the JSON data rearranged in some form and assign an ID to it. NOW:

1 - What is the server suppose to return in the HTTP response? A JSON containing the JSON provided by the clinet + the newly created fields, namely the ID of the new record?

2 - who is going to update the model in the client with these data? Me? Matter of fact I would like to tell the model in the client that a new ID has been assign to it by the server so that the next time I do `user.save()` I will obtain a PUT rather than a POST. But who is supposed to update the model in the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so this is my work flow for this

```
client -> create model and populate with data
client -> save model (model.save())
server -> create server side version of model using data, assign an id
server -> respond with success and the id of the newly created model
client -> in the success set the id to the one passed back
```

now the only potential issue i have with my work flow is if something did not get set in the server successfully but the model was still created, my client model would not reflect that of the server anymore, but i minimize this by returning error if the model could not be created exactly as passed.

And now i am able to call model.save() again this time having the id so initiating a PUT request

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation to a Backbone.Model
`After a successful server-side save, the client is (optionally) updated with the server-side state.`
So if you return a **valid** JSON **your model will be updated automatically**